# Using Task Scheduler vs Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, batch-file, tkinter, scheduled-tasks

I needed to perform a heavy operation while using a Tkinter GUI. So the GUI would stop responding as soon as the operation began. So, I had two choices(or that's what i think,as I'm new to python & programming as well): **MultiThreading** or **Schtasks** .
So, I chose the easier of the two,i.e **Schtasks**, as I'm working on a deadline(& I dont know much about Multithreading).

What I'm doing is accessing a python file from a different project.

I run batch files which is in this different project(which contains the desired python file that i need to run) to be run by **Schtasks**

Now the constraint is batch file can access only this python file & not a particular method present in that file(isn't it?) & I need to **access only a particular method** .

So, my question is:

Is the approach I'm using correct? If not what do you suggest would be better ? Or should I just switch to **MultiThreading**

Answer (score 1):

Your question opens a huge topic - what you are trying to do is generally not simple and can have large problems which you cannot even foresee if you don't know the topic of multitasking very well. One issue, for example, is synchronizing the access to the file you mention from within different threads or processes or tasks.

However, if you want to start somewhere and just want to write something which separates your GUI code from your computation code, I recommend you start here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html .